# Do I need a @LocalBean for @ConversationScoped?

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, cdi

My project is using JSF2.0 and WAS8.0. And I use a @ConversationScoped CDI bean as my page's backing bean. My original annotations for this bean are:

```
    @Named("myBean")
    @ConversationScoped
    @Stateful
```

Then when the page is being loaded, I got Property not found error. Seems the ELs are totally not working. Then I added @LocalBean (my backing bean MyBean does implement interface, but there's no @Local annotation on the interface):

```
    @Named("myBean")
    @LocalBean
    @ConversationScoped
    @Stateful
```

Then everything works nicely. Is it something specific in WebSphere? Or a common requirement for CDI ( I think I have seen some examples with neither @LocalBean nor implementing a @Local annotated interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems necessary to me, maybe the other beans you saw were not EJB beans:

> The unrestricted set of bean types for a session bean contains all
>   local interfaces of the bean and their superinterfaces. If the session
>   bean has a bean class local view, the unrestricted set of bean types
>   contains the bean class and all superclasses. In addition,
>   java.lang.Object is a bean type of every session bean.
>
> Remote interfaces are not included in the set of bean types.